# Is there a way to fetch data from an API that needs headers in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

I need to fetch all the data from my Cliniko API into a Google Sheets, but that I can do, if I could connect to that API...
On their docs, they only give an example to use with curl, I managed to transfer it to JavaScript to use with Apps Script. I think :(
Here's the doc for the API: https://github.com/redguava/cliniko-api

I tried lots of things to finally have that code here: That's what I think is closer to the real thing.

```
function dataOut() {


  var options = {
    "headers" : {
      "Authorization" : "MY_API_KEY",
      "Accept" : "application/json",
      "User-Agent": "GoogleAppsScript (me@gmail.com)"
  }
};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.cliniko.com/v1/users", options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
};
```

I got a 401 error on line 10. On the API doc, a 4xx is a missing/wrong required parameter(s).
I need it to log, that's the reason for the last line of code.

Thank you very much for any help.
p.s. The API key is working but may not have data in it, I just need to be able to fetch it without any errors, that's all

The working code is:

```
function dataOut() {


      var options = {
        "headers" : {
          "Authorization" : "Basic MY_API_KEY",
          "Accept" : "application/json",
          "User-Agent": "GoogleAppsScript (me@gmail.com)"
      }
    };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.cliniko.com/v1/users", options);
      Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    };
```

You need to encode the API key and put "basic" without quotes before it.

Comment: One of your problems is the incorrectly formatted Authorization header. [The github page you referenced explains how to generate it properly](https://github.com/redguava/cliniko-api#authentication). You probably just need to spend more time with the documentation.

Comment: Take a look at [this reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params).

Comment: I also made all this code by reading that reference @Cooper but thank you for linking it, it may help others

Comment: Thank you, but the answer is yes and no... I should have maybe googled everything I didn't know what was it but that's kinda stupid because there is a lot! I'm a real newbie here... And yes your right @Dimu Designs someone explains it to me in private, I needed to encode my API key and add basic in front of it. Like this: basic MY_API_KEY I hope it helps someone else